# Is this code declaring a type?

Tags: c

```
#ifdef _CPU_8BIT_INT_
// unsigned 8 bit
typedef unsigned _CPU_8BIT_INT_ u8 ;
```

What is the code above doing? Is it trying to declare a type? (type as in integer, char etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `typedef` is used to declare a type. From now on

```
u8 x;
/* Equivalent to. */
unsigned _CPU_8BIT_INT_ x;
```

Are you sure you're not better off using **`uint8_t` from `stdint.h`** ?